# execution of stored procedure :PL000103 error

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I am trying to execute a stored procedure which is already present in the schema.
After repeated attempts I am unable to make my query run as I am facing the following error:
Error report -

```
ORA-06550: line 2, column 2:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol " " when expecting one of the following:

   begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete
   exists prior
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

This is what I trying to execute :

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE
   P_RESULT_OUT      SYS_REFCURSOR;
   P_ERRORCODE_OUT   NUMBER;
   P_ERRORMSG_OUT    VARCHAR2 (2000);
BEGIN
   NKADM.BSCS_USAGE_QUERY_PKG.ZKSA_BILLED_USAGE_QUERY_SP ('CUST0000000763',
                                                          NULL,
                                                          NULL,
                                                          'ALL',
                                                          '20-04-2018',
                                                          '01-05-2018',
                                                          P_RESULT_OUT,
                                                          P_ERRORCODE_OUT,
                                                          P_ERRORMSG_OUT);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (P_ERRORCODE_OUT || '::' || P_ERRORMSG_OUT);
END;
/
```

Comment: Are you running this script in SQL\*Plus? Have you tried running it without the blank lines?

Comment: Code you posted seems to be OK (at least, as far as I can tell). Are you sure that this piece of code raised the error?

Comment: @Littlefoot - your edit has made the posted code easier for us to read. However it has obliterated the original layout, which was why I was asking about blank lines.

Comment: @APC, I don't think that it matters. PL/SQL allows blank lines, my code is full of them (to improve readability). OP's procedure call was written in a long, single line so - that can't be either. I *think* formatting didn't spoil anything important (but I do apologize if it turns out that I'm wrong).

Comment: I wonder if `the symbol " "` means there is a character somewhere in there which appears blank, but is not actually a space.